# EntityFramework how to write a custom function to use in anonymous type

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the need for a re-useable function that i can call in the creation of an anonymous type.

I've attempted it with the following, but get errors about converting a function to expression from EntityFramework.

Can anyone help me out.

```
var query2 = (from parts in cabinetOrderParts
              join header in headers
              on parts.SQLHeaderID equals header.SQLHeaderID
              join order in orders
              on parts.SQLOrderID equals order.SQLOrderID
              where parts.SQLHeaderID == sqlheaderid
              orderby parts.SQLOrderID
              orderby parts.CabinetDoorPartsID
              select new
              {
                  Height = doit.GetHeight(parts, order),
                  //a number of other parts, header and order fields omitted.

              });

public static class doit
{
    public static Expression<Func<ICabinetDoorPart, ISQLOrder, decimal?>> GetHeight(ICabinetDoorPart part, ISQLOrder order)
    {
        //parts.CutToHeight.HasValue ? parts.CutToHeight : parts.Height
        Expression condition = Expression.Condition(
            Expression.Constant(part.CutToHeight.HasValue),       Expression.Constant(part.CutToHeight), Expression.Constant(part.Height));
        var selector = Expression.Lambda<Func<ICabinetDoorPart, ISQLOrder, decimal?>>(condition);
        return selector.Compile();
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
I used Debugview and captured this Expression that entity framework is using.

```
.Lambda   #Lambda10<System.Func`2[<>f__AnonymousType1`2[<>f__AnonymousType0`2[Interfaces    .Shiloh.ICabinetDoorPart,Interfaces.SQLFilePro.ISQLHeader],Interfaces.SQLFilePro.ISQLOrder],<>f__AnonymousType2`1[System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal]]]>  (<>f__AnonymousType1`2[<>f__AnonymousType0`2[Interfaces.Shiloh.ICabinetDoorPar t,Interfaces.SQLFilePro.ISQLHeader],Interfaces.SQLFilePro.ISQLOrder]   $<>h__TransparentIdentifier1)
{
    .New <>f__AnonymousType2`1[System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal]](.If (
            ((($<>h__TransparentIdentifier1.<>h__TransparentIdentifier0).parts).CutToHeight).HasValue
        ) {
            (($<>h__TransparentIdentifier1.<>h__TransparentIdentifier0).parts).CutToHeight
        } .Else {
        (($<>h__TransparentIdentifier1.<>h__TransparentIdentifier0).parts).Height
        })
}
```

which i thought resembled this in c#

```
public static Expression<Func<object[], decimal?>> GetHeight(object[] value)
    {
        var exp = Expression.New(new { Height = new decimal?() }.GetType().GetConstructors()[0],
                                    Expression.Constant(10));
        var selector = Expression.Lambda<Func<object[], decimal?>>(exp);
        return selector;
    }
```

But still no joy!

Comment: What is the type of Height? I would assume it is int or some double or float. Yet your GetHeight function returns a highly complex type. It should return the expected type.

Comment: Doesn't the expression get added to the IQueryable and used by the provider to produce sql?

Comment: I intuit that it won't, but I can't really explain why.  You're assigning an expression tree to a property - EF isn't obligated to *execute* that expression tree.  Whereas, if you add `let height = doit.GetHeight(parts, order)` between your last `orderby` and the `select`, it should.  I think.

Comment: Thanks Amy, but that did not work either, same error. LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`3[Interfaces.Shiloh.ICabinetDoorPart,Interfaces.SQLFilePro.ISQLOrder,System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal]]] GetHeight(Interfaces.Shiloh.ICabinetDoorPart, Interfaces.SQLFilePro.ISQLOrder)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: @muscleman71 LINQ will appropriately guess the type of Height, but I'm curious what *you* think the type should be. Having an anonymous type with a member of type Expression<LotsOfComplexity> is unusual and I think you are misunderstanding LINQ.